# Find the sum $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}} + ...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{99}+\sqrt{100}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, radicals, telescopic-series

I would like to check I have this correct

> Find the sum 
>   $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}} + ...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{99}+\sqrt{100}}$$
>   Hint: rationalise the denominators to get a 'telescoping' sum: a sum of terms in which many pairs add up to zero.

I rationalised the denominators to get a series like this:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{2}}{-1}+\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{-1} +...+\frac{\sqrt{99}-\sqrt{100}}{-1}  $$
Which can be written:
$$\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{4}-\sqrt{3}...+ \sqrt{99}-\sqrt{98} +\sqrt{100}-\sqrt{99}$$
Which is the telescoping sum the question talks about.
Most of the terms drop out to leave 
$$-\sqrt{1} +\sqrt{100} = 9$$

Have I got this correct?

Comment: I think you got it right!

Comment: Yes what you've done looks right.Plus I also confirmed it using Wolfram Alpha ( [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F%28%E2%88%9A1%2B%E2%88%9A2%29%29%2B%281%2F%28%E2%88%9A2%2B%E2%88%9A3%29%29%2B...%2B%281%2F%28%E2%88%9A99%2B%E2%88%9A100%29%29) ) (8.999... = 9 )

Comment: Here you haven't mentioned the limit to your question
so i am assuming it to be 'n'
let the number of terms be up to n
rationalize each term in the expression for example ---
(1/(1+sqrt2))
=(sqrt2-sqrt1)/((sqrt2+sqrt1)*(sqrt2-sq… =(sqrt2-sqrt1)/(sqrt2^2-sqrt1^2) =sqrt2*sqrt1.(since sqrt(1) = 1)
perform the above step for all terms in your question
by doing that we get the expression -------
=sqrt2-sqrt1+sqrt3-sqrt2+sqrt4-sqrt3+..…
(all the terms cancel out with its corresponding opposite number,except sqrt1 and sqrt(n+1))
therefore answer is = sqrt(n+1)-1

Answer (score 3):

you could also do it by induction

conjecture: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}} + ...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{n}-1$ For $n \in [2,3,4 ...]$

For $n=2$:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}-1$$

For $n+1$: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}} + ...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}$$

$$= \sqrt{n} - 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}$$

$$= \sqrt{n} - 1 + \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}$$

$$= \sqrt{n+1}-1$$

$$Q.E.D.$$

Comment: This isn't a different answer; it's a (needless) formalism of the OP's.  If you wanted to be totally formal about your proof, you could do it this way, but it takes longer to write out.