# Evaluate Algebraically: Sequences and Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Evaluate Algebraically (Sequences and Series): [image: Evaluate]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the sum $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}} + ...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{99}+\sqrt{100}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464223/find-the-sum-frac1-sqrt1-sqrt2-frac1-sqrt2-sqrt3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{r+1}+\sqrt{r}}=\frac{\sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r}}{(\sqrt{r+1}+\sqrt{r})(\sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r})}=\frac{\sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r}}{r+1-r}=\sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r}.$$

So

$$\sum_{r=1}^{99}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r+1}+\sqrt{r}}=\sum_{r=1}^{99} (\sqrt{r+1}-\sqrt{r})=\sqrt{100}-\sqrt{1}=10-1=9.$$